# Sending images from arduino to android over bluetooth

Tags: android, image-processing, bluetooth, arduino

I want to hook a camera up to an arduino which will send images to an android over bluetooth. I don't mind a delay in image transfer (once it's not to large). I then will process the images on the android (probably with the OpenCV library, motion tracking). This is a pan/tilt camera set up, the arduino will tell two motors how to behave based on the the images. How can I send this data over bluetooth or other wireless means? What type of camera is best for this situation?

Comment: I would do as Odebugg said and use a Raspberry Pi. That way you can have the image processing done right on the Pi instead of having to send it to Android, then back again. If you must use an Arduino, check out the CMUcam4, which is a camera board with an on-board processor to take the brunt of the load. http://www.cmucam.org/projects/cmucam4

Comment: Thanks! I still need a way to send the images to the android though.

Comment: Also something a little cheaper. A usb-camera and bluetooth shield are much cheaper than this CMUcam.

Comment: But what will you do with a USB camera? An arduino can't communicate directly with a USB camera.

Comment: Or well something like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10061

Comment: That would work. Keep in mind Arduino doesn't have the memory to store images, so as you are receiving the data, you should be sending it out to the Android device. Bluetooth would be the easiest wireless solution. As the pixel information comes in from the camera, you send those pixels right back out to a bluetooth module in serial port mode (SPP), then that module sends it wirelessly to Android.

Comment: Do you know any existing or useful code that would help with this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/linksprite-serial-cam-arduino/downloads/list could I use this code but send it through the bluetooth instead?

Comment: Yes, in that link there is the code labeled "Take picture and send it over a software serial port", you can connect a bluetooth module to that software serial port and it will directly send that data to the Android device.

Comment: Also make sure your android device supports the SPP profile. I think all newer ones do support it, but you never know.

Comment: Do you manage to do it? Can you share your solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use an Arduino? I do not know if it will have the processing power needed for image processing. Have you looked into using a Raspberry Pi? You can install Java on it, and use the Pi4J library to access its GPIO. The people from Raspberry Pi recently created a camera module for easier integration with the main board.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, *no*, I don't think you can use an arduino for that:

the problem you will encounter is that the image capturing library you may find added to the bluetooth (or wifi) library (and the whole network stack) will fill your arduino up! Remember that you have only 32k of flash to put everything in, it's less than an Atari 2600. So you'll need a bigger arduino (like the arduino mega) which is close to the price of a beaglebone or a rasppi.

So to sum up, same conclusion as the others: just use a bone or a rasppi.

Though, here's one hack though that could help you doing what you want:

- http://www.ladyada.net/make/IoTcamera/

it's a hack, because the arduino only copies the image over the eyefi, and the eyefi does not need to be handled by the arduino like a bluetooth/wifi shield.

Comment: what type of image capturing libraries are used with bluetooth? Or can I simply tell the arduino to take a picture and convert it to bits then send it over bluetooth?

Comment: I have done far simpler configurations in an arduino that filled the memory. e.g. having the Ethernet library along with a lolshield, or doing an i2c to ethernet gateway...

Comment: Do I really need the image capturing library or can I just convert a single image to bits/whatever and send? And then keep repeating. I'm a complete beginner so I'm just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Well, it's not an image *processing* library I'm talking about, but just an image *capturing* library. You need to make the arduino operate the image device you plug on it, and that's what such a library is for! Don't even think about doing complex image operations on the arduino, it will just forward the data the capture device will give to the network.

Comment: What about something like this: http://www.evola.fr/product_info.php/en/linksprite-jpeg-color-camera-ttl-interface-p-172 along with https://code.google.com/p/linksprite-serial-cam-arduino/downloads/detail?name=test_cam_sserial.ino&can=2&q=

Comment: and what about that one: https://www.adafruit.com/products/397, which is the one used in the tutorial I linked you!

Comment: I would prefer bluetooth over wifi. The google code I just updated my comment with could work with the LinkSprite camera?

Comment: well, you can always try, you'll see if the `JPEGCamera` library and the bluetooth library you'll need will fit in the memory of the arduino. I just fear that it won't. The only good aspect of using the Eyefi is that it's close to only opening the serial line from the arduino point of view, no fancy thing to handle.